# Do you use "abet" positively?

Tags: word-usage, word-meaning

Longman dictionary defines “abet” as: to help someone do something wrong or illegal.

Oxford dictionary: abet somebody: to help or encourage somebody to do something wrong

That's what I learned until I came across the following sentence:

> The photo editing software is sure to abet my odds of winning the photo competition.

There's also the explanation that it means "to encourage or support a behavior or action.

So, do you use the word positively as well?

Comment: I would never use 'abet' that way. A person abets another person.

Comment: The dictionaries are right. The words "to abet my odds" suggests the writer was thinking of  some expression from gambling. [Etymonline](https://www.etymonline.com/search?q=abet) says the word comes *"from Old French abeter "to bait, to harass with dogs," literally "to cause to bite," from a- "to" + beter "to bait."* So it seems always to have had a sense of wrongness.

Comment: All right, I will go by the dictionary then. Thank you guys.

Comment: I appreciate your correction, ColleenV.